# Check how many times a string appear in listbox

Tags: c#, regex, listbox

I have a listbox, which I load items from a button with this code:

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(line);
    }
}
```

The file I load contains list (.txt) in format:

```
username:password:proxy
```

My goal is to find the proxy only, and count how many times each proxy appears.

So I use this code:

```
List<string> proxies = new List<string>();
foreach (string s in listBox1.Items)
            {
                proxies.Add(Regex.Match(s, @"\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\:\d{2,5}\b", RegexOptions.Singleline).ToString());
            }
```

Now I have all proxies from the file in a list, but how can I save it in format so that each proxy shows how many times it appeared?

For example:

```
proxy1 - 8 (times)
proxy2 - 5 (times)
proxy3 - 4 (times)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to print out a *report* in the format provided, i.e.

```
  proxy1 - 8 (times)
  proxy2 - 5 (times)
  proxy3 - 4 (times)
```

you can use *Linq*

```
String report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
  File.ReadLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt")
    .Select(line => line.Split(':')[2])
    .GroupBy(item => item) 
    .Select(chunk => String.Format("{0} - {1} (times)", chunk.Key, chunk.Count())));

Console.Write(report);
// Or 
// listBox1.Text = report;
```

Comment: I think what the user is asking is, he wants the "Text" of the item change from "proxy1" to "proxy1 - 8".  Is this correct?

Comment: @JasonGeiger This is exactly what I wanna do, except it outputs all of them as 1 string, I was trying to put them 1 by 1 in a new listBox.

Comment: I like this answer, it's very short and does what I need it to, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
listBox1.Items.Add(line);
```

You want to do something like this...

```
ListBox1.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("Label", "Value"))
```